# Python: CSV file is still Blank after writing Data

Tags: python

I have a Tuple result from mysql like this :

```
sqlResult=({'Count': 1L, 'gname': 'Anron may'}, {'Count': 1L, 'gname': 'Anchy de'}, {'Count': 1L, 'gname': 'abby ras'}, {'Count': 2L, 'gname': 'Akki nome'}, {'Count': 41L, 'gname': 'Archenemy'}, {'Count': 1L, 'gname': 'Antony papa'}, {'Count': 1L, 'gname': 'Dead zombie'})
```

I am trying to save this data to CSV file like this

```
import time
csvName="Gnames-and-count-"+str(int(time.time()))
csvPath="/home/sean/Desktop/"+str(csvName)+str(".csv")
writer = csv.writer(open(csvPath, 'wt'))
for results in sqlResult:
    writer.writerow([results['gname'],int(results['Count'])])
```

The file is created at the following path but nothing is there on the file.
Is there any obvious thing i am missing? .Please guide me.

Comment: How about storing the reference to file handle, and **explicitly** closing it later on?

Comment: @Thrustmaster Thanks for pointing it out.I was not closing the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to close the file. Let `with` do it for you.

```
with open(csvPath, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for results in sqlResult:
        writer.writerow([results['gname'],int(results['Count'])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly write into csv file write into standard out put and saves the result in file_name.csv

```
import csv
import sys
...
...

writer=csv.writer(sys.stdout)

...
```

then for taking output in csv

you can write command like this :-

```
$ program_name > my_spreadsheet.csv
```

Hope it will help you...

Comment: @girijesh I can totally do that but while setting up the cronjob it will be a pain for me because then i cannot change the filename according to the  current timestamp automatically.

Comment: @saunjean for installing this script in cronjob you can write a shell script where you can use command like this program_name > my_spreadshet`date '+%Y%m%d'`.csv

Comment: Thanks grijesh, but i didn't want to complicate it.It is better to keep single file until it is needed.

Comment: @saunjean yes saun you are right it is better to keep single file.But iam giving  alternative to this...:)